# SharePoint 2013 - update item in Current Item - triggers multiple instance of sharepoint workflows

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I have a infopath library and i have multiple workflows in it (close to 6 workflows). one of them is sharepoint 2013 workflow and others are sharepoint 2010 workflow. when the sharepoint 2013 workflow runs (on create and on item modified) it has a line called update item in Current Item. i think this like is triggering 3 instances of all the workflows. how can we restrict all the workflows to be run only once.i have already unchecked the Automatically update the workflow status to the current stage name checkbox

it should run only once

Comment: It might be necessary to create a WorkflowStatus plain text field, clear it every time the infopath form saves, and when the workflow executes set its value. Put conditions in your workflows to only proceed when it is blank. If you can, use SystemUpdate, but i don't think there is an action for this, unless it's a code-based workflow. Re Nintex, update the item with call service / call API actions (specifically call SystemUpdate) instead of the standard update item actions (unless there is a system update checkbox in there now)